# Getting item from Sqlite Query database

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a database created with table name "Accounts" There are THREE columns. One is named as `userId` and other is named as `accountType`. The third account is of `accountId` The function i want to create is

```
     private int getNextAccountIdForUserId (String ourUserId, int ourAccountType)
            {
              int nextId = kFirstIDValue;
              Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, ACCOUNT_TABLE, new String[] {"userId", accountType},"accountId", null, null, null, null, null); 
              ...
              //what more to do to get the accountId of ourUserId and ourAccountType

            }
```

I want to retrieve the accountId for the specific accountType and userId i have defined. Please tell the correct formate of query used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SQL like below:

```
String sql = "SELECT userId, accountType, accountId FROM Accounts WHERE accountId ="+accountId;
Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql  , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true,ACCOUNT_TABLE, new String[] {"userId","accountId", "accountType"},"userId='"+sp_userid+"' and accountType='"+sp_accounttype+"'", null, null, null, null, null);  // sp_userid and sp_accounttype are the specific userid and accounttype
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
Cursor cursor = getDB().rawQuery("select accountid from accounts where accountType=? and userId=?", new String[] { accountType,userid}); //your variables in the array
```

hope it helps.